# jQuery Address plugin - How to get link clicked on in $.address.change()

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-address

I am trying to use the Address plugin from http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ and I really need to be able to access the link or object that was clicked on that triggers the $.address.change function.

So basically, I have a link that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="active" rel="address:/show-my-activity">Activity</a>
```

And then I have the $.address.change function that looks like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $.address.internalChange(function (e) {
         // this is where I need to get the obj of what was clicked to trigger it
         // find out what the e.value is, and do the ajax needed
    });
</script>
```

I have already looped through all the properties of "e" but I can't find anything that references me back to the object that was clicked. Here is what comes back from the "e" variable...

```
undefinedtype value :change
timeStamp value :1317227369056
jQuery1317227368799 value :true
value value :/show-my-activity
path value :/show-my-activity
pathNames value :show-my-activity
parameterNames value :
parameters value :[object Object]
queryString value :
result value :undefined
target value :[object Object]
currentTarget value :[object Object]
handler value :function (e) {
    var str;
    var obj = e;
    for (prop in obj) {
        str += prop + " value :" + obj[prop] + "\n";
    }
    alert(str);
    if (e.value === "/showMyActivity") {
    }
}
data value :undefined
handleObj value :[object Object]
preventDefault value :function () {
    this.isDefaultPrevented = Z;
    var a = this.originalEvent;
    if (a) {
        a.preventDefault && a.preventDefault();
        a.returnValue = false;
    }
}
stopPropagation value :function () {
    this.isPropagationStopped = Z;
    var a = this.originalEvent;
    if (a) {
        a.stopPropagation && a.stopPropagation();
        a.cancelBubble = true;
    }
}
stopImmediatePropagation value :function () {
    this.isImmediatePropagationStopped = Z;
    this.stopPropagation();
}
isDefaultPrevented value :function Y() {
    return false;
}
isPropagationStopped value :function Y() {
    return false;
}
isImmediatePropagationStopped value :function Y() {
    return false;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the documentation here http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/

You can do this in your link's click event.

```
$('a').click(function() {  
    $.address.value($(this).attr('href'));  
});
```

Then grab it with `event.value`.

**Edit:** I updated the above solution with what I think might be helpful. Alternatively you can have a global variable that you assign your object to within its click event. Then you can use that variable within your other function.

Comment: That's not the right way to implement it though. You are supposed to pass in the address to the value so the plugin knows what URL it's supposed to go to. In this case, you'd pass in "/show-my-activity". If you passed in the entire object, what would the value be for the URL?

Comment: Yeah, I just checked it, and doing this totally breaks the function of this plugin. It's expecting a URL to be passed into the value.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to be able to reference the jQuery object of the link clicked?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like to do, but here's the problem. The $.address.vaule is what the URL is going to be when you pass it in. So if you pass an entire object in, then the URL will be http://www.domain.com/#[Object] [object]. Instead, I need it to be a real URL like http://www.domain.com#/show-my-activity or something. Technically, I could re-select the link that I clicked on based on the "rel" with something like 

$("a[rel*='/show-my-activity']")

...but I really don't want to have to reselect every link on this event cause that's really inefficient.

Comment: It looks like there's no way for me to get the object directly from the event in the $.address.change() function then, huh? I guess I'll have to just select the object based on the href tag again. Assigning global variables doesn't sound like a clean solution because you'll basically have to add an additional click event to every single link you want to have use this address feature. I'm not assigning the address feature to the link via a click event, I'm doing it by putting rel="address:/show-my-activity" in the link's properties.